# combine multiple lambda expressions with different types to one expression

Tags: c#, expression, lambda

I want to combine some separated lambda expressions and build one final expression of them.

example classes :

```cs
class Address {
   public string city { get; set; }
   public string country { get; set; }
}
class ClassA {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Address address { get; set; }
}
class ClassB {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ClassA objectA { get; set; } 
}
```

each class have one lambda expression :

```cs
Expression<Func<ClassA,bool>> classARule = a =>
                     a.Id > 1 && a.address.city == "city1" || a.address.country == "us"

Expression<Func<ClassB,bool>> classBRule = b => b.Id == 100
```

because `ClassB` has one property of `ClassA` it's possible to create an expression with both conditions. example :

```cs
// I want to create this expected object at runtime using classARule and classBRule 
Expression<Func<ClassB,bool>> expected = b =>
     (b.Id == 100) &&
     (b.objectA.Id > 1 && b.objectA.address.city == "city1" || b.objectA.address.country == "us")
```

if I want to generate expected expression at runtime I should somehow convert `a` parameter of `classARule` to `b.objectA`

the problem is I know how to combine two expressions but I don't know how to replace `a` parameter with some other object. in this case `b.objectA`

---

## **Update - To avoid more confusion**

**the goal is to achieve `Expression<Func<ClassB,bool>> expected` expression at runtime using `classARule` and `classBRule`**

---

Comment: Do you just want your func to take 2 parameters instead of one?  I'm mildly confused what you're asking

Comment: @Jonesopolis no, I want to dynamically combine all rules based on each property of the class.

Comment: these rules apply some limitation to my database query so for example because ObjectB have a reference to the ObjectA i want to add objectA limitation to the final query at runtime

Comment: it's possible to do that at compile-time and change `a` to `b.objectA` property. like the above example. my question is how should I do that at runtime?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I wrote a lot of expressions is the past but now I am confused too :) I think it's normal in this case.  xD

Comment: How about create base class and put the common property and derive your both class from it so you filter can be used ‘Expression<Func<baseclass,bool>>’

Comment: @Eldho these classes are an example of my entity framework model. I can not change database schema because I want to get a query of these entities later.

Comment: anyway, I answered my question. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, I solved the problem. 
The final result here is for others if they encounter such a problem.

```cs
public static Expression<Func<B, bool>> Combine<B, A>(this Expression<Func<B, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<A, bool>> expr2, Expression<Func<B, A>> property)
{
    // this is (q) parameter of my property 
    var replaceParameter = property.Parameters[0]; 

    // replacing all (b) parameter with the (q)
    // these two lines converts `b => b.Id == 100` to `q => q.Id == 100` 
    // using ReplaceExpVisitor class
    var leftVisitor = new ReplaceExpVisitor(replaceParameter); 
    var left = leftVisitor.Visit(expr1.Body);

    // the property body is 'q.objectA'
    var replaceBody = property.Body;

    // now i'm replacing every (a) parameter of my second expression to 'q.objectA'
    // these two lines convert this statement:
    //   a.Id > 1 && a.address.city == "city1" || a.address.country == "us"
    // to this :
    //   q.objectA.Id > 1 && q.objectA.address.city == "city1" || q.objectA.address.country == "us"
    var rightVisitor = new ReplaceExpVisitor(replaceBody);
    var right = rightVisitor.Visit(expr2.Body);

    // creating new expression and pass (q) reference to it (replaceParameter).
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<B, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left, right), replaceParameter);
}

// this is a simple class to replace all parameters with new expression
private class ReplaceExpVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _newval;

    public ReplaceExpVisitor(Expression newval) => _newval = newval;

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _newval;
    }
}
```

usage :

```cs
var result = classBRule.Combine(classARule, q => q.objectA);

// or
Expression<Func<ClassB,bool>> result =
          Combine<ClassB, ClassA>(classBRule, classARule, q => q.objectA);

/* 
result is equal to the expected expression in the first example now
result output :

q => 
  ((q.Id == 100) && 
  (((q.objectA.Id > 1) && (q.objectA.address.city == "city1")) || 
  (q.objectA.address.country == "us")))

*/
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KnV3Dz

Comment: You should also include an explanation (some comments in the code should be enough)

Comment: @Nkosi I added some comments to my code. hope it helps you to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: I under stand the code. I suggested adding comments for those who come to review your answer in the future who may not under stand what is being done and why.

Comment: Glad you figured out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compile the expression:

```
class Address
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}

class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectA objectA { get; set; }
}


Expression<Func<ObjectB, bool>> expected = b =>
    (b.Id == 100) &&
    (b.objectA.Id > 1 && b.objectA.address.city == "City1" || b.objectA.address.country == "US");

// Compile the Expression
var expectedItems = expected.Compile();

List<ObjectB> objBs = new List<ObjectB>();

var address = new Address();
var objA = new ObjectA();
var objB = new ObjectB();
address.city = "City1";
address.country = "US";
objA.Id = 1;
objB.Id = 100;
objA.address = address;
objB.objectA = objA;
objBs.Add(objB);

address = new Address();
objA = new ObjectA();
objB = new ObjectB();
address.city = "City2";
address.country = "US";
objA.Id = 3;
objB.Id = 100;
objA.address = address;
objB.objectA = objA;
objBs.Add(objB);

// Use expectedItems
var result = objBs.FirstOrDefault(b => expectedItems(b));
```

Comment: my question is not about loading items. I don't have the `expected ` expression I want to create that.

Comment: I just demonstrated the Expression and the Compile. This code works (with the compile), yours is missing the compile and so does not. What part of the expression you want to create is missing?

Comment: Is it because I used ObjectA (not shown here - in the class definitions) and ObjectB instead of ClassA and ClassB? - Added them anyway.

Comment: no I just renamed class names to simplify the example and avoid more confusion.
`Expression<Func<ClassB, bool>> expected` this is an example of what I want to create using two other expressions (A&B rules). i don't want to manually create this expression.
`the goal is to achieve expected expression at runtime using classARule and classBRule`

Comment: Ahhh, sorry mis-interpreted what you were trying to do. It will depend on how you are storing/supplying the expressions for each class - can you have a method that can retrieve them to be joined? Are they passed in via delegates? In the end, you will need to build the the expression tree looping through the different objects (ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, etc.) along with the properties to be checked to build a single expression. However, a single expression expects one object type - you have two currently. That makes me think that you have to check each expression one after the other.

Comment: If you have ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC, what would the expression expect? Func<Class?, bool>. This makes me think you need to check them separately - not a single expression as you have shown. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: my target expression type is dynamic. if you look at the above example I want to join two expressions because  ClassB has a reference to the ClassA I know I can combine ClassA expression with ClassB expression because of these references. I'm trying to provide my half solution for this problem and I will update the post in the next few minutes.

Comment: and about your question, I use entity framework to retrieve data. I want to pass this expected expression to where method of EF. `context.ClassB.where(expected)`